# Accessing Mac hard drive from Iphone app via USB

Tags: iphone, usb

Do I need to use the external accessory API for this? Or are there other ways/possible at all using the SDK? I'd like to access the contents in a specific folder on a Mac from the Iphone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No USB needed. [Turn on web sharing on the Mac](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8292.html) and point your copy of Mobile Safari at the local computer's web address.